# Twig check multiple values

Tags: php, templates, twig

I have about 5 or so tables that are booleans.  I want to test all of them and if one or more return true then to do something.

So far I have tried something like

```
{% if product.is_red == true %}

<h1>Has colors</h1>

{% elseif product.is_yellow == true %}

<h1>Has colors</h1>

{% elseif product.is_green == true %}

<h1>Has colors</h1>

{% elseif product.is_purple == true %}

<h1>Has colors</h1>

{% elseif product.is_black == true %} 


{% endif %}
```

But if anyone of them returns true then it will say

```
Has Colors
```

whatever the amount of times it returns true.  Is there any way to check all of them and if one more returns true then returns "Has colors"?

Comment: Why not just add an extra method on your model? Which does the same checks. This way you have good semantics in your view, which does not need to be updated when a color is added.

Comment: @Yoshi, I think model methods should not be exploited for this simple job.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu I disagree wholeheartedly. The model is exactly the place for *simple* decisions. Putting that decision in the view makes it completely unreusable. If you need it in another view, or in code, you'll have to write exactly the same logic again. It's just awful.

Comment: Surely not for the organisation where the jobs are distributed. @Yoshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to work with a `flag` in `twig` to keep track if one or more colors are specified. A shorter example of the code would be (*should also work with an object `product`)*:

```
{% 
    set product = {
        'is_red'     : false,
        'is_yellow'  : false,
        'is_blue'    : true,
        'is_green'   : false,
    }
%}

{% set has_color = false %}
{% for color in ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', ] %}
   {% if product['is_'~color] is defined and product['is_'~color] %}{% set has_color = true %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if has_color %}
<h1>Has color</h1>
{% endif %}
```

[fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/hrfdtl)

Comment: While your solution is perfectly viable, I would still vote for a different approach: Just implement `hasColor()` as a function for the product entity.