# Twig check if value in array is true

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I have an array which contains booleans.  How do I search the array to see if one or more is true and then display the `<h1>` something once?

Here is my code so far

```
{% set guides = 
              [
                 product.is_user_guide,
                 product.is_product_guide,
                 product.is_installation_guide
              ] 
              %}

               {% for guide in guides %}
                  {% if (guide) %}
                  <h1>There is a guide!</h1>
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
```

In the above code it finds 2 values in the array to true and displays the h1 twice.  How can I modify it so it only displays once?

Comment: You need to work with a [flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156701/twig-check-multiple-values/39159539#39159539) or write the logic inside your controller or extend twig with a function

Comment: Maybe solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672796/how-can-i-use-break-or-continue-within-for-loop-in-twig-template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [*containment operator* `in`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator):

```
{% set guides = [
    product.is_user_guide,
    product.is_product_guide,
    product.is_installation_guide
] %}

{% if true in guides %}
   <h1>There is a guide!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Demo: http://twigfiddle.com/pf4xjp